# NoSuchMethodError when opening question on android app 0.1.28

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install 0.1.28 on a device running API 16 (4.1)
2. Open the app
3. Open any question

Result: crash, `NoSuchMethodError`

Stack trace top:

```
09-11 11:29:52.657    3424-3424/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: [v0.1.28] com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.PrettyWebView.getDisplay
        at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.PrettyWebView.setPostBody(PrettyWebView.java:228)
        at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.common.PrettyWebView.setPostBody(PrettyWebView.java:135)
        at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.QuestionFragment.fillView(QuestionFragment.java:162)
        at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.QuestionFragment.onCreateView(QuestionFragment.java:86)
```

[`View.getDisplay()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDisplay()) requires API level 17. My device is running API level 16 which AFAIK should be a supported level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the minimum API Level is 14. I have just pushed 0.1.30 to Google Play to fix this (0.1.29 was never published).